# Select most recent rows from inner joined tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, inner-join

I want to get the most recent row from each inner joined tables. Both tables have a `timestamp` field. Below is what I have so far. But it only targets for `table1` how about for `table2`?

```
SELECT
`table1`.`fieldX`, 
`table2`.`fieldY`
FROM `db`.`table1`
INNER JOIN `db`.`table2`
ON `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`id` 
WHERE `table1`.`id` = ?
ORDER BY `table1`.`timestamp`
DESC LIMIT 1
```

table1

```
row_id
id
fieldX
timestamp
```

table2

```
row_id
id
fieldY
timestamp
```

Both tables can have repeating ids. It was designed this way to store older versions of the data entries.

For example: `table1` can have 3 rows with the same id while `table2` can have 2 rows of the same id. I want to get the latest row from both tables.

Comment: Can you show the table structure?

Comment: @ArunKrish check out edits. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use can use it like this if you want recent record from table2

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t1.fieldX ORDER BY t1.timestamp DESC),',',1) as field_x, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.fieldY ORDER BY t2.timestamp DESC),',',1) as field_y
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON(t2.id = t1.id)
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY t1.timestamp
```